# Recreate project from .jar file

Tags: java, jar, recreate

Is there any chance, to recreate a (netbeans-)project from a .jar file?
Becuase I trusted some silly cryption-software that corrupt's my file.

Is their any suggestion or solution?
I already extracted the .jar file with terminal commands 'jar xf MyJarFile.jar'.
But I can't read the code in it...

Comment: Is your source code in your jar? Is that what you are after?

Comment: What means, you can't read the code? Is the sourcecode (.java) in the JAR, or only the compiled .class files? In the latter case, you are pretty much lost. You could try a Java Decompiler.

Comment: only the .class files :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could decompile the jar into the sources and then create a new project and drag all the sources into your src folder. I like using JD-GUI for decompiling .jars: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend using JD-GUI, it helped me a lot when my simple text editor corrupted my .java files and I was able to convert the classes back into source using it.

Answer (score 0):

delete the $ files first, then Jad is the best, jdgui makes errors.